# Designed a D FF using Strucural Verilog but the Q output is showing up as 'Z'

Tags: verilog, fpga, hdl

I want it to show the output of the flip flop but instead it lists the output as 'Z'. How can I get it to do this?

Code:

```
 module d_flip_flop_edge_triggered(Q, Qn, C, D);
   output Q;
   output Qn;
   input  C;
   input  D;

    wire Q;
    wire Qn;

   wire   Cn;   
   wire   Cnn;  
   wire   DQ;   
   wire   DQn;  

   not(Cn, C);
   not(Cnn, Cn);   

endmodule
```

This is the test bench - I think the problem lies here.
TestBench:

```
module ffTB;

// Inputs
reg C;
reg D;

// Outputs
wire Q;
wire Qn;

// Instantiate the Unit Under Test (UUT)
d_flip_flop_edge_triggered uut (
    .Q(Q), 
    .Qn(Qn), 
    .C(C), 
    .D(D)
);

initial begin
    // Initialize Inputs
    C = 0;
    D = 0;

    // Wait 100 ns for global reset to finish
    #100;
  C = 1;
    D = 1;
    #100;
  C = 0;
    #100;
  C = 1;
    #100;
  C = 0;
    #100;
  C = 1;
    #100;
  C = 0;
end

endmodule
```

Thank you my grade depends on it!

Comment: Do you really think using two not gates shall make D-ff? What is the use of `Q`,`Qn`,`D` inputs? Where is clock and reset signals? Refer [this link](http://www.asic-world.com/verilog/gate2.html) for an idea about D-ff.

Comment: D normally represents Data in not reset. As others have said your not driving the Q output so it is z. z means high impedance or not driven.

Comment: I forgot to post the whole problem. I figured it out thanks guys.

Answer (score 1):

Your model for the flip-flop is completely wrong. (Sorry, but it's true.) With the exception of the input `C`, none of the inputs or outputs are connected to anything! As a result, the testbench shows that the outputs are floating, which is denoted by the value `Z`.

Answer (score 0):

Your D flip-flop RTL,

```
module d_flip_flop_edge_triggered( output reg Q, 
                               output wire Qn,
                               input wire clk, 
                               input wire rst_n,
                               input wire D
                             );

always @ (posedge clk or negedge rst_n)
begin
  if (~rst_n)
  begin
    Q  <= 1'b0;
  end
  else
  begin
    Q <= D;
  end 
end

assign Qn = ~Q;

endmodul
```

And Testbench,

```
module ffTB;
reg clk;
reg rst_n;
reg D;
wire Q, Qn;

d_flip_flop_edge_triggered d_flip_flop_edge_triggered_inst (Q, Qn, clk, rst_n, D);

initial 
begin
  clk = 1'b0;
  rst_n = 1'b0;
  D = 1'b0;
  #10 rst_n = 1'b1;
  #600 $finish;
end

always clk = #5 ~clk;

initial
begin
  repeat (100)
  begin
    D = $random;
#5;
  end
end

endmodule
```

with simulation, [image]